# How do execute an SSRS report with a parameter from within a cursor driven SQL stored procedure via SQL agent job

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I wish to have a nightly SQL Server Agent job that simply runs an SSRS report that has one parameter driven by an SQL cursor in a stored procedure and save the generated PDF into a file system directory. One report would be produced for each parameter value picked up in the cursor.

This is based on a SQL query that detects row changes in a table for previous 24 hours for example.

I need to write one PDF per row into a windows file system directory.

So I was wondering if it is possible to execute an external SSRS report via this process and export that report as PDF to the directory?

Comment: I think you would find it much easier to write a windows service to do the same thing. Accessing URL's from within SQL Server is a right PITA. And writing to the file system is similar.

Answer (score 2):

A subscription can be created that generates a PDF to a folder.

The subscription be triggered by a stored procedure using the AddEvent SP in ReportServer with the subscription ID of the subscription.

```
EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID;
```

If the parameter needs to be updated, you can get the XML from the Subscriptions table and update it with .modify.

Here's an example of how it is used:

```
--GET SUBSCRIPTION PARAMTERS AND EXTENSIUONS
SELECT @EXTENSION_SETTINGS = ExtensionSettings, @PARAMETERS = [Parameters]
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
WHERE SubscriptionID = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID;

--LOOP SETUP USING ROW_NUM FROM QUERY - YOUR METHOD MAY DIFFER
SET @RECORD_ID = 1
SET @MAX_RECORD_ID = (SELECT MAX(RECORD_ID) FROM #RECORDS)


WHILE @RECORD_ID <= @MAX_RECORD_ID 
BEGIN


--SET EXTENSION OPTIONS FOR FILENAME AND PATH IF NECESSARY
SET @EXTENSION_SETTINGS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="FILENAME"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@FILENAME")');
SET @EXTENSION_SETTINGS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="PATH"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@PATH")');

--SET REPORT PARAMETER ID FROM VARIABLE @ID
SET @PARAMETERS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="ID"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@ID")');


--UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION PARAMETERS 
UPDATE ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
SET ExtensionSettings = CAST(@EXTENSION_SETTINGS AS VARCHAR(8000)), 
    [Parameters]      = CAST(@PARAMETERS AS VARCHAR(8000))
WHERE SubscriptionID = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID


EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID;     --ADD SUBSCRIPTION TRIGGER EVENT 

--SET @RECORD_ID = @RECORD_ID + 1
END
```